# TeXStudio could not start command (ProTeXt)

Tags: installing, texstudio, protext

I am running Windows 7 and I have installed the ProTeXt package. I am using MiKTeX and TeXstudio however my TeXstudio seems not to work as I get the following error message:

```
Error: Could not start the command: "texstudio_Hp6136".ps
```

This is all of my text in my file:

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\begin{document}
   Blah 
\end{document}
```

Then I hit <kbd>F1</kbd> (Quick Build) and I actually tried all the other buttons for `latex` and DVI and `pdflatex`.

What is/could be wrong with TeXstudio?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Have you tried running `pdflatex myfile.tex` from the command line? A minor point- `dfrac` will need the `amsmath` or `mathtools` package to be loaded...

Comment: I edited my post. It does not matter what I put in my document.

Comment: Please, post an image showing your Options>Configure>Commands window from TeXstudio. Probably you have to setup the right path for the executable files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TeXStudio menu choose <kbd>Options</kbd>→<kbd>Configure TeXStudio</kbd>,
select <kbd>Quick Build</kbd>, option <kbd>pdfLaTeX + pdf Viewer</kbd>.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition I would like to propose,

`option >> configure >> commands>> 
Latex >> "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\latex.exe" -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

and

`PdfLaTex>>"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

in some cases it works as the editor finds the miktex directory.